# When people mention storing files on the File System, is that referring to a folder within the app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to store pdf files that will keep increasing with time on a folder for my app. But I'm not sure which method is consider 'good practice' between if I should store it in a folder within the project architecture (i.e. inside Content folder) or in a folder outside the app. I tried searching online but most people just mention 'File System' and don't give examples on where do they store it.

So my question is, when people mention storing files on the File System, do they usually mean storing it in a folder inside the app (like Content folder) or do they mean storing it in a folder outside the app?

For example: let's say my apps folders/files are within the container folder: /Container/AppFolder/. Should I store the pdf files on the apps Content folder (i.e. /Container/AppFolder/Content) or should I create a new folder OUTSIDE the apps folders to hold these pdf files? (i.e. /Container/PDFFiles, so basically two folders within the container folder - one folder for the pdf files and the other folder for the app)? Which one is consider a good practice? I have considered just putting these files on the Content folder but as the amount of files keep increasing I'm not sure if is bad practice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it where ever you want on the server, the program will just need proper permissions to that location (I use the IO namespace). However you should put thought into how to organize the files and folders. Is each file to be tied to a specific ID or just all in 1 folder? Think of things you'll need to handle like invalid file names (special characters), duplicate file names etc. Is the location strictly 1 way (upload only)? Or are you enabling download functionality? If you have download functionality stress security, probably creating a download.aspx page specifically for handling download requests and authentication.